# How can i get a particular field corresponding to a question from mongodb in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a rest api that fetches the answer corresponding to the question from mongo db. However, i am new to mongo so is there any way that I can give response to the user based on the specific question from the database.

Here is my code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/questionandanswer");
var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    question: String,
    answer: String
});
var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);


app.get("/getanswer",function (req, res)  {
   User.find({}).then(eachOne =>{
       res.json(eachOne);
   })
});

app.post("/addquestion", (req, res) => {
    var myData = new User(req.body);
    myData.save()
        .then(item => {
            res.send("question saved to database");
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("Unable to save to database");
        });
});
var port=process.env.port || 5005;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```

Here is my database image file:
[mongodb database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CshZn.png)

My code return me all the stored answers however i only want answers to specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use specific Id or Question

```
 User.find({"question" : "how are you"}).then(eachOne =>{
       res.json(eachOne);
   })
```

Or

```
User.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5c73....7f")}).then(eachOne =>{
           res.json(eachOne);
       })
```